# How can I use log4net in Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, log4net, class-library

I want to config a log4net in Class library Project and use it on mvc project for example.

The point is have a few projects (web api, mvc app, etc) with a reference to Common project (class library) with log4net configurated to write.

I already did that, but log4net dont write anything.

Class Library:

```
public class Log
    {
        private readonly ILog _log;

        public Log()
        {
            _log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        }

        public void write(string value)
        {
            _log.Info(value);
        }

    }
```

mvc controller for example:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Log oLog = new Log();

            oLog.write("ABABABAB");

            return View();
        }
```

Config from Class Library: (App.config)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="MyLogg.txt" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="Header" value="" />
        <param name="Footer" value="" />
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <!--LogLevel: OFF, FATAL, ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, ALL -->
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 6):

Class library config file is not important, Startup project config file is considered. Hence, if you write this configuration into your startup project config file, it probably works expectedly.

If you want to manage configuration from one config file, you can generate log4net.config file and you  can load it like that:

Note: if you create separate config file in common project, you change CopyToOutputDirectory properties as `always` or `if newer`.

Config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<log4net>

<logger name="log4netFileLogger">

<appender name="log4netFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString">
    <conversionPattern value="C:\Logger\%date{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" />
  </file>

  <param name="RollingStyle" value="Date" />
  <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="false" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%newline%newline%date [%thread] %-5level - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>

<root>
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="log4netFileAppender" />
</root>

</logger>

</log4net>
```

Log class :

```
public class CustomLogger
{
    private readonly ILog _log;

    public CustomLogger()
    {
        var baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        var configFileDirectory = Path.Combine(baseDirectory, "log4net.config");

        FileInfo configFileInfo = new FileInfo(configFileDirectory);
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(configFileInfo);

        _log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("log4netFileLogger");
    }

    public void Info(string value)
    {
        _log.Info(value);
    }
}
```

config file properties :

[image: config file properties]

log file:

[image: log file]

Web App needs pre-build events :

```
xcopy /E /Y /R "$(ProjectDir)..\CommonNetFrameworkLibrary\log4net.config" "$(ProjectDir)"
```

[image: pre-build]

NOTE: In Logger class, below code is important. If you do not search base directory, logging only work for Console app. Reason is that: console app search file for `bin` directory, but web app search file for `C:\ProgramFiles\IIS`.

```
var baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
var configFileDirectory = Path.Combine(baseDirectory, "log4net.config");
```

Comment: Thank you.What is appenderName ?

Comment: In your case `LogFileAppender`.

Comment: I add my test code to end of answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank You @Adem Catamak. I think that I know what is wrong with me. You use a Console Application Project and I'm using WebAPI Project and it dont work.

Comment: Console app “log4net.config” is search under bin directory. In web app it search under web project directory. You can change ediy csproj file and every time it can copy log4net config file from common to web app folder. If you want I can supply csproj file

Comment: I edited answer. WebApp and Console app can write log with last update of log class. Problem was finding config file:)